# Internet Explorer 6 does not display my navigation

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I am having a nightmare, been trying all day with this, and searched google with no success. I have a little navigation that is floated to left and I wanted to make it work for RTL language. It worked fine in FireFox but IE6 does not display it at all.

Can someone tell me why?

The HTML is the default markup.. nothing fancy

```
<div id="topnav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><?php print NAV_HOME; ?></a></li>
<?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&depth=1&title_li='); ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

```
#topnav ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}

#topnav li {
    float: right;
    padding: 0;margin:0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background: url(img/topnav_br.png) no-repeat left center;
}
```

The point is that it will be floated to left, but LI items will start from right to left because its RTL lanuage.. but this code above shows nothing in IE6 but works in FF.

Somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks!

Comment: As web devs, do we really need to continue support for IE6?

Comment: Can you post the HTML example where you are using this CSS as well?

Comment: Take the IE6 debate somewhere else. Its not up to you to determine that for the poster and is a distraction from the question at hand.

Ahmad, do you have a link to a page where this problem can be viewed?

Comment: I posted the markup. its basic. john, unfortunately I am working on localhost, btw If i changed the float: right; to float: left; on #topnav li everything renders fine but from left-to-right which what my customer does not want. he wants it right-to-left.. and i only get the issue on ie6

Comment: Can you just use tables or have to use the ul li?  And Chris, many network admins don't allow people to upgrade.  It's not even a choice.

Comment: rball - yes it has to be tableless.

Comment: Update> If i added width to #topnav ul it renders well in IE6 but this creates another problem. The menu items are dynamic and they can be more or less of this width I specify.. so its certainly not my holy grail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information. If you did not specify a width, IE will default to 100% of the available room (within its parent).

The following code (with background colors) clearly displays (in IE6) with the list items floated all the way to the right within the ul (and actually 30px off the display window with a double margin on the left). We do not know what your containers are (if any) or what doctype (if any) you are using. We do not know what else is being floated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<head>
<title>Float right li test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
body { margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#topnav ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
background-color: yellow;
}

#topnav li {
    float: right;
    padding: 0;margin:0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
background-color: pink;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="topnav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Selection 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Selection 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<p>This is where the page content will go.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have been bitten by the ["hasLayout" bug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250481.aspx). Try this:

```
#topnav ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
    zoom:1;
}
```

Comment: I tested this but with no success. The menu content is still hidden.. as if it does not exist there.. weird

Comment: hmm i'll check it out when i get home - don't have ie6 here at work.

Comment: Thanks for your try at least, appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The one thing I can see here that will cause a layout issue in IE6 is the left margin and float on the topnav ul.  This will make IE6 double the margin.  Add "display:inline" to topnav ul

## topnav ul {

```
float: left;
margin: 0 0 0 30px;
display: inline;
```

}

Comment: I agree with you, but the menu content is still hidden completely.

Comment: Could you create a sample test page on a server somewhere I could take a look at?